# What is the best way to handle a conditional number of member variables?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, design-patterns

I am trying to write a C++ library to plot either 2D or 3D data. My idea is to have a `Plot` class that contains all the information regarding the axes, title, legend, and so on. So `Plot` would have a member `Axes`, a member `Title`, etc.

class Plot
{
public:
    plot() {...}
private:
    Axes axes;
    Legend legend;
    ...
}

I want the API to be as intuitive as possible, so that it could be used (easy example) as follows:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<float> x_data { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    std::vector<float> y_data { 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0 };
    std::vector<float> z_data { 8.0, 7.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };

    Plot plt;    // initializes a generic instance of a plot

    // The user can decide to plot 2D data
    plt.plot2D(x_data, y_data);            // only takes 2 input parameters

    // Or to plot 3D data
    plt.plot3D(x_data, y_data, z_data);    // takes 3 input parameters
}
```

The problem is (for example) `Plot`'s `Axes` member.

In the 2D case I would like `Axes` to be something like:

```
class Axes
{
public:
    Axes() {...}
    std::string getAxesInformation()
{
    // does something with axes x and y
}

private:
    Axis x;
    Axis y;
}
```

While in the 3D case I would like it to be something like this:

```
class Axes
{
public:
    Axes() {...}
    std::string getAxesInformation()
{
    // does something with axes x, y AND z
}

private:
    Axis x;
    Axis y;
    Axis z;
}
```

How should I handle a different number of member variables? One option of course to save a `bool` to keep track of the existence of `z` and stuff, but that doesn't seem ideal.

I would like `z` not to be instantiated at all.

Comment: Variadic template? That's the first thing that springs to (my) mind when reading your question.

Comment: why not simply a `std::vector<Axis>` ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl thank you for the suggestion, I will have to look it up.

Comment: @idclev463035818 that would be an option, but I'm afraid it would limit the possibilities in the future. The example I presented for `Axes` is pretty basics, but I'm not sure `std::vector` would provide all the necessary functionalities for other classes.

Comment: @giacomo-b I have no clue what you mean. There is no obvious disadvantage of a `std::vector<Axis>` compared to the three members `x`,`y`,`z` you have now

Comment: everything you can do with `Axis x;` you can also do with an element in a `std::vector<Axis>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::unique pointer to do so (that can guarantee to not instantiate and also an easy way to check if an element as been set or not):

```
class Axes
{
public:
    Axes(...)
    {}

    std::string getAxesInformation()
    {
      if(x)
       // do something with x
      if(y)
       // do something with y
      if(z)
        // do something with z
    }

private:
    std::unique<Axis> x;
    std::unique<Axis> y;
    std::unique<Axis> z;
}
```